# How to set system path variable in github action workflow

Tags: linux, docker, pipeline, github-actions

I was wondering how I can set the system path variables in the GitHub actions workflow.

```
export "$PATH:$ANYTHING/SOMETHING:$AA/BB/bin"
```

Comment: Hi amr. Did you try doing it the same way than for other [environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables) on github actions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the following run command to set a system path variable in your actions workflow.

Syntax:

```
echo "{path}" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

```
- run: |
   echo "$AA/BB/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

Additionally, if you have downloaded some binaries and trying to set its path, GitHub uses a special directory called `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` as your current directory. You may need to specify this variable in your path in that case.

```
- run: |
   echo "$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/BB/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Bash shell

```
- name: Add to PATH
  shell: bash
  run: |
    echo "Folder PATH" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

For Powershell as a shell:

```
- name: Add to PATH
  shell: pwsh
  run: |
    echo "Folder PATH" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append
```